# How to remove style attributes from tags on SummerNote onPaste?

Tags: jquery, wysiwyg, text-editor, rich-text-editor, summernote

Is it possible to remove all the style attributes when the user paste html content into Summernote texteditor?

For Example : (Input)

```
 <p style="font-weight:500; color:#000;">Hello World </p>
 <div style="display:block"> I am a Div content </div>
```

Expected Output after paste:

```
 <p>Hello World </p>
 <div> I am a Div content </div>
```

I want to Implement something like in Javascript/Jquery

```
$('tag').removeAttr("style");
```

Is there any in-built options or feature in SummerNote text editor to do this?

Thanks In advance

Comment: I'm interested in this too. I wonder if https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/303 will help us.

Comment: Or https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/remove-inline-styles/

Answer (score 9):

I've finally done it adapting an another solution (how to paste as plain text: [summernote doesn't allow to format pasted text after writing onpaste event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33799909/summernote-doesnt-allow-to-format-pasted-text-after-writing-onpaste-event))

After succeed to paste in plain text using the solution above, just had to change text to html and remove style as you suggested:

```
$('.summernote').summernote({
  callbacks: {
    onPaste: function (e) {
      var bufferText = ((e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData('text/html');
      e.preventDefault();
      var div = $('<div />');
      div.append(bufferText);
      div.find('*').removeAttr('style');
      setTimeout(function () {
        document.execCommand('insertHtml', false, div.html());
      }, 10);
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know browser compatibility of this solution, i only tested on Chrome. But i think it's not so hard to modify.

Comment: Works fine in FF v77 too. Should not really depend on the browser as long as it's standard JS (or jQuery for a matter of fact).